# Insert or replace in MSSQL in Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, sql-server-2008

I have the following code in python:

```
import pyodbc

def insertPrintedPath(self, pth):

        con = pyodbc.connect('blabla')
        cur = con.cursor()
        tm = str(datetime.datetime.now())

        cur.execute("insert into dbo.printedPaths \
                    (pth, tm) values \
                    (?, ?)", pth, tm)
        cur.close()
        con.commit()
        con.close()
```

`pth` is `unique` in MSSQL DB. Could I use something like `insert or replace` in SQLite?
which does not work in MSSQL.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197733/does-sql-server-offer-anything-like-mysqls-on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Merge` in `MSSQL`

So replace your

```
insert into dbo.printedPaths \
                    (pth, tm) values \
```

As follows;

<strike>MERGE
    INTO dbo.printedPaths WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target
    USING (SELECT pth pth, tm) AS source (pth, tm)
    ON (target.pth = source.pth)
    WHEN MATCHED  THEN UPDATE
        SET tm = tm
    WHEN NOT MATCHED
        THEN INSERT (pth, tm) VALUES (pth, tm);</strike>

```
def insertPrintedPath(self, pth):

        con = pyodbc.connect('blabla')
        cur = con.cursor()
        tm = str(datetime.datetime.now())

        cur.execute("    MERGE \
    INTO dbo.printedPaths WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target \
    USING (SELECT pth, tm) AS source (pth, tm) \
    ON (target.pth = source.pth) \
    WHEN MATCHED  THEN UPDATE \
        SET tm = tm \
    WHEN NOT MATCHED \
        THEN INSERT (pth, tm) VALUES  \
                    (?, ?)", pth, tm)
        cur.close()
        con.commit()
        con.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it on monday, because I'm on Linux now.

Comment: Could you please show the whole cur.execute() statement, I'm not quite clear about it.

Comment: @xralf, you better try it :) - Read the answer again and give it a shot.

Comment: It ends with error: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Comment: @xralf, In your question there is no '@P1', so the problem should be elsewhere.

Comment: Here is my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62001156/pyodbc-incorrect-syntax-near-p1) with complete snippet. Actually, I solved it programmatically with select, delete and insert from Python code. But I'm still interested in the correct answer.

Comment: @xralf, even that doesn't have '@P1' ? :O When you pass just Insert statement, was it OK?

Comment: @xralf, get the prepared SQL in python side, as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071166/print-the-actual-query-mysqldb-runs
And show the SQL statement.

Comment: @xralf, and it has something to with the syntax
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50728621/pyodbc-execute-variable-becomes-p1

(I'll correct my answer - accordingly)

Comment: @xralf, try now